# How do I merge two columns from two datasets in r and include all the elements from one data frame except when they are NA?

Tags: r, merge, dataset, latitude-longitude, coalesce

I have two datasets. One is substantially longer than the other one, but I want to put the latitudes/longitudes from the smaller dataset onto the larger one.

My first data set (the long one), has some wrong latitudes and longitudes (they don't actually say correct and wrong, they are coordinates):

```
country city latitude longitude
usa      xyz  wrong   wrong
usa      abc  wrong   wrong
usa      iff  correct correct
usa      sfo  correct correct
usa      lax  correct correct
```

Second data set is shorter but contains correct lats and lons only for coordinates that need fixing:

```
country city latitude longitude
usa      xyz  correct  correct
usa      abc  correct  correct
```

I essentially want to get the following:

```
country city latitude longitude
usa      xyz  correct correct
usa      abc  correct correct
usa      iff  correct correct
usa      sfo  correct correct
usa      lax  correct correct
```

To be clear, all the latitudes and longitudes in the smaller data set are correct and therefore should always replace the values in the larger one.

Any suggestions for how to do this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please use backtick code-fences, not single-quote fences. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```r
merged <- merge(original, fixes, by = c("country", "city"), all = TRUE)
merged
#   country city latitude.x longitude.x latitude.y longitude.y
# 1     usa  abc      wrong       wrong    correct     correct
# 2     usa  iff    correct     correct       <NA>        <NA>
# 3     usa  lax    correct     correct       <NA>        <NA>
# 4     usa  sfo    correct     correct       <NA>        <NA>
# 5     usa  xyz      wrong       wrong    correct     correct
merged <- transform(merged,
  latitude = ifelse(is.na(latitude.y), latitude.x, latitude.y),
  longitude = ifelse(is.na(longitude.y), longitude.x, longitude.y)
)[, c("country", "city", "latitude", "longitude")]
merged
#   country city latitude longitude
# 1     usa  abc  correct   correct
# 2     usa  iff  correct   correct
# 3     usa  lax  correct   correct
# 4     usa  sfo  correct   correct
# 5     usa  xyz  correct   correct
```

---

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
original %>%
  left_join(fixes, by = c("country", "city")) %>%
  mutate(
    latitude = if_else(is.na(latitude.y), latitude.x, latitude.y),
    longitude = if_else(is.na(longitude.y), longitude.x, longitude.y)
  ) %>%
  select(-contains("."))
#   country city latitude longitude
# 1     usa  xyz  correct   correct
# 2     usa  abc  correct   correct
# 3     usa  iff  correct   correct
# 4     usa  sfo  correct   correct
# 5     usa  lax  correct   correct
```

---

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
originalDT <- as.data.table(original)
fixesDT <- as.data.table(fixes)
fixesDT[originalDT, on = c("country", "city")][
 ,c("latitude", "longitude") :=
    .(fifelse(is.na(latitude), i.latitude, latitude),
      fifelse(is.na(longitude), i.longitude, longitude)) ][
        , .(country, city, latitude, longitude) ]
#    country city latitude longitude
# 1:     usa  xyz  correct   correct
# 2:     usa  abc  correct   correct
# 3:     usa  iff  correct   correct
# 4:     usa  sfo  correct   correct
# 5:     usa  lax  correct   correct
```

or if you prefer the pipe look with `data.table`, then

```r
library(magrittr)
fixesDT[originalDT, on = c("country", "city")] %>%
  .[, c("latitude", "longitude") :=
        .(fifelse(is.na(latitude), i.latitude, latitude),
          fifelse(is.na(longitude), i.longitude, longitude)) ] %>%
  .[, .(country, city, latitude, longitude) ]
```